# Sublime - how can I paste and convert indenting to match the destination file?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Say I copy some four-spaced text to the clipboard:

```
var double = function(number){
<four spaces>return number * 2
}
```

And paste it into a file that is tab separated. **How can I make pasting automatically indent with the local file's own indentation?** Eg, when I paste into a file with tab set up for indentation, it should automatically convert to:

```
var double = function(number){
<a tab>return number * 2
}
```

PS. I know about the `paste_and_indent` shortcut. That doesn't do what I'm asking.

Comment: A possible manual workaround is to use the Command Palette. There are commands for **Convert to Spaces** and **Convert to Tabs**. Because of fuzzy matching, you can usually get to it quickly by typing `ctspace` or `cttab`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there are commands for **Convert Indentation to Spaces** and **Convert Indentation to Tabs**.

[image: sublime_tabs_to_spaces]

These can be also called with the `expand_tabs` and `unexpand_tabs` commands, respectively, so if you want these to fire every time you paste into a file, you could create a small plugin.

Go to `Preferences > Browse Packages` and create a new file (e.g. `autoindent.py`) under the `User` folder. Add the following:

```
import sublime_plugin

class AutoIndentListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_post_text_command(self, view, command_name, args):
        if command_name in ['paste', 'paste_and_indent']:
            s = view.settings()
            tab_size = s.get('tab_size')
            if s.get('translate_tabs_to_spaces'):
                view.run_command('expand_tabs')
            else:
                spaces = 4
                if tab_size == spaces:
                    view.run_command('unexpand_tabs')
                else:
                    view.run_command(
                        'set_setting',
                        {"setting": "tab_size", "value": spaces})
                    view.run_command('unexpand_tabs')
                    view.run_command(
                        'set_setting',
                        {"setting": "tab_size", "value": tab_size})
                    view.run_command('unexpand_tabs')
```

Every time you use the `paste` or `paste_with_indent` shortcuts, it checks the `translate_tabs_to_spaces` setting of the current view (**Indent Using Spaces** in the menu above) and runs the appropriate command on the file.

---

**Edit**

If you know how many spaces the code you are pasting has I think something similar to the above is probably the simplest. It essentially just sets the tab size to the size of the spaces you are indenting (to 4 in this case) if not the same, converts the 4-spaced code to tabs, then sets and converts to whatever the tab size was originally set to.

If you need something more involved (that detects the indentation of the pasted code, for example) and feel like having a look at the code, unzip `Default.sublime-package` from the main Sublime Packages folder and have a look at:

- `detect_indentation.py`: Contains code that is called when you select
  **Guess Settings From Buffer** from the menu (above) that could potentially be modified to guess the indentation of the pasted code.
- `indentation.py`:  It contains the code for `expand_tabs` and `unexpand_tabs`. Both are subclasses of `TabCommand`, so you can
  subclass that and implement your own.

E.g.

```
from Default.indentation import TabCommand

class UnexplodeTabs(TabCommand):
    def do(self, edit, only_leading=True, spaces=None, **kw):
        # your code
```

Then you can replace the above with:

```
import sublime_plugin

class AutoIndentListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_post_text_command(self, view, command_name, args):
        if command_name in ['paste', 'paste_and_indent']:
            s = view.settings()
            if s.get('translate_tabs_to_spaces'):
                view.run_command('expand_tabs')
            else:
                view.run_command('unexplode_tabs')
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer and exactly what I wanted! Unfortunately, after following the steps (and restarting sublime) pasting 4 spaced text into a document with 'Spaces: 2' the spacing doesn't change. Do you have any suggestions to help me investigate? Thanks again for an excellent answer.

Comment: @mikemaccana No problem. See my edit. Hope it helps.